# Tratar array na controller Cakephp 3

Tags: php, array, cakephp

Entao gente eu tenho duas controllers, a produtosvendas e a vendas, em que no produtosvendas eu seleciono produto com checkbox e envio por um buttom para outra pagina, e na controller produtosvendas eu teria que tratar a array, e ela seria enviada para vendas para mostrar na tela os produtos que eu selecionei.

View da ProdutosVendas

```
<tbody>
    <?= $this->Form->create("carrinho", ["class " => "form-add", "action" => "carrinho", "controller" => "Produtos-Vendas"]) ?>
<button type="submit" class="btn-success btn">Carrinho (<span id="additem"></span>)</button>
<?php foreach ($produtos as $produto): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $this->Number->format($produto->id) ?></td>
        <td><?= h($produto->name) ?></td>
        <td><?= h($produto->cor) ?></td>
        <td><?= h($produto->tecido) ?></td>
        <td><?= $this->Number->format($produto->estoque) ?></td>
        <td><?= $this->Number->format($produto->preco) ?></td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn-success btn addcart">+ Adicionar</button>
            <input type="checkbox" style="" name="check[]" class="checkbox" value="<?php echo $produto['id']; ?>">

        </td>
    </tr>   
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

Controller da ProdutoVendas

```
public function carrinho() {
    $check = $this->request->getData();
    if ($check == null) {
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    } else {
        return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'vendas', 'action' => 'index']);
    }
}
```

Meu problema é que eu nao sei como tratar essa array $check para que na tela vendas seja exibido o que eu selecionei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri como resolver meu problema, minha view continua a mesma, mas na minha controller ficou assim:

```
    public function carrinho(){

    $check = $this->request->getData();
    if ($check == null) {
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }else{
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['check'] = $check;  
        return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'vendas', 'action' => 'index']);
    }
}
```

E na view que eu gostaria de exibir/passar esses dados eu somente iniciei a sessão check novamente e extrai os valores da session.